# How can I make this javascript Up/Down Numeric input box using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Ok I have this Up/Down Numeric input box :

**Markup:**

```
<div class="rotatortextbox">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtrunningtimeforfirstlot" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">0</asp:TextBox>
    In mins)
</div>
<div class="rotatorarrow">
    <input id="UpButton" value="&#9650;" type="button" onmousedown="timerID = setInterval(function(){FactUp()},100);" onmouseup="clearInterval(timerID);" />
    <input id="DownButton" value="&#9660;" type="button" onmousedown="timerID = setInterval(function(){FactDown()},100);" onmouseup="clearInterval(timerID);" />
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var timerID = 0;
function FactDown() {
    var obj = document.getElementById("<%=txtrunningtimeforfirstlot.ClientID%>");
    var num = parseInt(obj.value)

    if (isNaN(num)) {
        return;
    }

    num -= 1;
    obj.value = num;
}

function FactUp() {
    var obj = document.getElementById("<%=txtrunningtimeforfirstlot.ClientID%>");
    var num = parseInt(obj.value);

    if (isNaN(num)) {
        return;
    }

    num += 1;
    obj.value = num;
}
```

This works perfectly fine. But how can this be made in Jquery such that I do not need to create separate `FactUp` /`FactDown` functions for every such textbox?

I was hoping to find out a way of doing it using .closest method of Jquery. This way I would not have to specify #id of textboxes again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer to this myself, so I am posting it here:

**Jquery:**

```js
 var intervalId;
 $(".up").mousedown(function() {
   var box = $(this).closest('div').find('.Rbox');
   intervalId = setInterval(
     function() {

       $(box).val(parseInt($(box).val()) + 1);
     }, 100);
 }).mouseup(function() {
   clearInterval(intervalId);
 });


 $(".down").mousedown(function() {
   var box = $(this).closest('div').find('.Rbox');
   intervalId = setInterval(
     function() {

       $(box).val(parseInt($(box).val()) - 1);
     }, 100);
 }).mouseup(function() {
   clearInterval(intervalId);
 });
```

```css
.up,
.down {
  font-size: 6px;
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
}
  .rotator  span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rotator">
  <span><input type="text" class='Rbox' value="0" /></span>
  <span><input class='up' value="&#9650;" type="button" />
    <input  class='down' value="&#9660;" type="button" /></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `.Net framewotk 4.5` and above simply use `TextMode="Number"` as an attribute of textbox. This will automatically increase decrease on key up/down.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtrunningtimeforfirstlot" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" TextMode="Number">0</asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: `Cannot create an object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBoxMode' from its string representation 'Number' for the 'TextMode' property.`

Comment: Use this as attribute of textbox just like i have cretaed the textbox.

Comment: Which .Net version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Code as below: This code is just for your reference which will demonstrate how you can change values of textbox without creating any function..

```
<input type="text" ID="txtrunningtimeforfirstlot" value="0" />

<input id="UpButton" value="&#9650;" type="button" onclick="alert($('#txtrunningtimeforfirstlot').val());$('#txtrunningtimeforfirstlot').val(parseInt($('#txtrunningtimeforfirstlot').val())+1)" />
```

Comment: that is still a lot of repition of code. I was thinking of doing it using `.closest ()` method of jquery , so that i dont even have to mention ids.

Comment: why not id? using closest(), prev(), next() is going to be issue whenever you change the place of your elements.

Comment: Well I am just looking for the easiest (least code) way. I am not likely to change the position of the elements.moreover element will always remain inside  rotatorarrow and rotatortextbox class div.

Comment: Plus, it increments only on click, not on hold.

Answer (score 0):

With Vanilla JS you could do this.

```
var timerID = 0;
function NewFactFunction(action) {
    var obj = document.getElementById("<%=txtrunningtimeforfirstlot.ClientID%>");
    var num = parseInt(obj.value)

    if (isNaN(num)) {
        return;
    }
    if(action === "up"){
        num +=1
    }
    else{
    num -= 1;
    }
    obj.value = num;
}
```

Then click events for the up and down button will be `"timerID = setInterval(function(){NewFactFunction("up")},100);"` and `"timerID = setInterval(function(){NewFactFunction("down")},100);"` respectively.